# MySQL Connector/c (libmysqlclient) missing header file my_config.h file

Tags: mysql, c, mysql-connector

I am trying to build a MySQL client only in C using Code Composer Studio to run on a micro without an RTOS.  Its only function is to  push a fixed format record to the server with no other features.  I have downloaded the Connector/c source files and added all the "include" files to my build.  I am getting 1 build error indicating that the #include "my_config.h" file can't be found.  The reason is that it doesn't exist in the distribution from MySQL.com. The documentation seems to indicate that it is part of the server package but I downloaded that also and it is not included.  The comments indicate this file defines the platform specific characteristics but gives no clue as to what they might be.  Where can I get this file and what information should it contain??

Comment: What exactly have you downloaded? Where from? Can you link to the documentation?

Comment: I have downloaded open source  "MySQL Connector/C 8.0" as well as the older version 5.7 from MySQL.com with similar results.  No config.h file anywhere in the download.

Comment: It was part of the package on my system.  I installed from mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-src.tar.gz.  I'm not sure why there is no source download for the newer versions.  Maybe because oracle took over the project.  Maybe it's there and I just don't see it...

Comment: It looks like the current source is here: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/tree/8.0/client .  You might be missing more than just the one file.

Comment: I do see the file in the server package but I am confused as to why I would need files out of the server package since I am trying use only a few of the connector/c driver functions to push my data.  The file seems to define specifics about PC architectures and I am using a micro without an operating system.